# как измерить время выполнения кода в python?

Tags: python, pycharm

...есть ли в PyCharm встроенная возможность отслеживать время выполнения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import time 

start = time.time() ## точка отсчета времени

##код программы

end = time.time() - start ## собственно время работы программы

print(end) ## вывод времени
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import timeit
code_to_test = """
a = range(100000)
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i*2)
"""

elapsed_time =  timeit.timeit(code_to_test, number=100)/100
print(elapsed_time)
```

#все что внутри тройных ковычек проверяется